# How to consume REST web service in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I am new in Drupal. Can anybody tell how to consume REST web service in Drupal 7?
I am trying to use WSClient Module in Drupal 7 for consuming the web service. It didn't have proper documentation. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Better you ask only after Googling your issues and learning tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's Services https://www.drupal.org/project/services is an excellent module for REST services.

You can also try [RESTful web services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws)